# Install adb enabled setting from zip

Tags: settings, 4.3-jelly-bean, system

Is it possible to make a zip file, similar to the one that installs GApps, that stores ADB debug mode as a system setting? Maybe somehow modify a system bootup script to change the ADB debug mode setting to on? I'm setting up a testing environment, and I can't have a factory reset turn off ADB.

update:
I think I've almost got it - I have a rooted deice using CWM recovery, and I am using SuperSU for root permission management. I unpacked the .zip that the CWM installs `su` from, and added a modified `/system/build.prop` to the update, as well as a command to turn on adb in `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db` using `sqlite3`, but I think it require root access, and `SuperSU` has default access to `su` set to 'prompt'. Is there a way I can modify it to be 'grant' by default?

useful links:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326806/enable-usb-debugging-through-clockworkmod-with-adb

Answer (score 2):

For those who are looking for an answer to this question: you can enable adb from a zip file that you install through recovery. I modified Superuser.zip from http://download.chainfire.eu/351/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v1.65.zip What I did was I modified `system/build.prop` and added `persist.service.adb.enable=1` at the bottom, I also added `ro.setupwizard.mode=DISABLED` to disable the setup wizard which gets annoying if you wipe or flash often. Then I added a precompiled `sqlite3` (don't have a link, I got it from my company's repo) to `system/bin` and the line `sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "UPDATE global SET value=1 WHERE name='adb_enabled'"` to `system/etc/install-recovery.sh` (although some people say modifying `settings.db` is optional.)
Unfortunately it seems adb still requires you to accept the rsa certificate until you unpack boot.img and modify /default.prop