# Enable usb debugging mode from adb under clockworkmode "Broken digitizer"

Tags: adb, usb

My friend brought me a Xtreamer Q mobile phone with broken screen, clockworkmode is working, but USB debugging mode is disabled, I found some posts about how to enable it from adb i tried them and none of them worked.
here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326806/enable-usb-debugging-through-clockworkmod-with-adb
and from this tutorial i learnt how to edit build.prop file.

http://www.modaco.com/topic/328943-quick-guide-to-modifying-buildprop-with-adb/
the commands i have used are: adb pull, adb remount, adb push.
While i was under clockworkmode i mounted system and i pulled build.prop then i added this line to it persist.service.adb.enable=1, used remount then pushed the file after that reboot, but i couldn't find the device in adb when it have booted normaly.
Next i tried to set adb_enabled to 1 in /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db by following some steps from here

ttp://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=774507
and it also didn't worked "The device was not listed".
Also i have tried this zip file from clockworkmode it didn't work too...

[Install adb enabled setting from zip](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54487/install-adb-enabled-setting-from-zip)

**My phone do not support USB org cable**

my files after editing:

https://www.mediafire.com/?1q13igpc981vydu